# User home directory issue

Tags: solaris

recently i have created the user on solaris it has been created successfully  when i see the details of the user by logins and id command it shows all the details but when i am trying to switch that user and  cd to its directory  it throws error like no directory. What would be the possible cause. User is not getting his directory

Below is the output of some command :
 bash

```
bash-3.2# id user1
uid=6032(user1) gid=300(mqm)

bash-3.2# logins -x -l user1
user1        6032    mqm             300
                        /export/home/user1
                        /usr/bin/ksh
                        PS 020515 7 91 7
bash-3.2# su - user1
su: No directory!
bash-3.2# cat /etc/passwd | grep -i user1
user1:x:6032:300::/export/home/user1:/usr/bin/ksh
bash-3.2# cd /export/home/user1
bash: cd: /export/home/user1: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is /export an NFS mount maybe and exported with no_root_squash, preventing you from creating the home directory, or did you simply forget to create it?

Comment: I have created the the directory because you can see in logins commands output as above

Answer (score 1):

The directory

```
/export/home/user1
```

Does not exist. You will need to create it

```
mkdir /export/home/user1
```

You'll then need to set the ownership using `chown`. You'll also need to create dotfiles.

---

It may be easier at this point to remove the user see `userdel -r` and recreate it using the `-m` switch to `useradd`, this will create the users home directory etc

Oracle have some [great documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1451/gkhqx.html) on this, you really need to read it.

Comment: There is no need for userdel. He can use: usermod -d /export/home/user1 -m

Comment: I have ran the above command(usermod -d /export/home/user1 user1 ) but have the same issue; so i need to use -m too in this command i mean after users directory please suggest .

Comment: What doesthe dot files refers to sorry for asking i m new to solaris pardone me . does it refers to user hidden files ...

Comment: @zuberuber I don't have easy access to a Solaris box to check right now but would like to know, does the usermod ... -m create the .files ?

Comment: @lain no, what kind of .files do you expect from usermod command?

Comment: @zuberuber (it's been a while but as I recall) useradd usually copies the dotfiles (.profile etc) from /etc/skel when creating a user account so using usermod here just leads to the OPs next question ... Perhaps given the OPs skill delete/recreate would be much easier.

Comment: @lain usermod doesn't copy dotfiles, only useradd. He'll have to do it manually.

Comment: @zuberuberSo given the OPs skill that's going to be easy for them not! Delete and recreate is much easier in this case.

Comment: Hi All this issue has been resolved as i created the directory and chnaged the ownership . Thanks all for your input. I appreciate for your quice resposne.